find value in column, which contains list and take another value from next column and put it in first table to new column
I have two tables
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1}, {'a': 2}, {'a': 8}])
df1['b'] = ""

df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'e': [1,2,3], 'f': 1},{'e': [4,5,6], 'f': 2},{'e': [7,8,9], 'f': 3}])
       e  f

I would like to insert a value into df1['b'] from df2['f'] based on the condition that value in df['a'] is somewhere in df2['e']
Mostly I would use apply/map
df1['a'].apply(lambda x: function)
I can get the specific value I need
df2['f'].loc[df2['e'].apply(lambda y: value_to_look_for in y)].item()
but when I put it together
df1['a'].apply(lambda x: (df2['f'].loc[df2['e'].map(lambda y:x in y)].item()))
I'm getting an error
"ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar"
Can I ask for a solution, what am I missing?

what is your expected output?

I would explode, create a mapping Series, and map:
df1['b'] = df1['a'].map(df2.explode('e').set_index('e')['f'])

Output:
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  1
2  8  3

Intermediate mapping Series:
df2.explode('e').set_index('e')['f']

e
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    3
8    3
9    3
Name: f, dtype: int64


this is working as expected, thank you

IIUC, you can create a mask using apply then use that to replace the values in place with loc:
m = df2["e"].apply(lambda x: df1["a"].isin(x).any())
df1.loc[m, "b"] = df2["f"]

   a  b
0  1  1
1  2   
2  8  3

